# MySQL: How to detect export?

Tags: mysql

I want to have a script monitoring MySQL Service for running export.

I thought of monitoring linux process list for services like mysqldump or mysqldumper. But i think this is not so reliable since there could be other tools (e.g. phpmyadmin, adminer, MySQL Workbench, etc...) used for export.

But are there any more reliable ways of monitoring database exports, or selecting really huge datasets like in an export scenario?

Comment: What is the reason you want to "monitor" such exports?